# Why would Dr. Stone's presence have saved Elinore?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

While Cyborg and his mother were driving home from the football game, their car was struck by another vehicle. Cyborg survived but his mother didn't. Cyborg claimed that if his father had been with them, his mother would still be alive:

> Cyborg: **If you were there, Mom would still be alive**.

Why would Dr. Stone's presence have saved Elinore?

Comment: I don't have all details in my mind, but I guess he meant Dr. Stone's availablity to his family could have put them in a restaurant instead of road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scene where the road accident is shown, we see that it was a [T-bone collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_collision), with the other vehicle impacting the driver's side of the Stone's car.

We're not specifically told this, but it can reasonably be inferred that at least part of the reason Vic survived while his mother, Elinore, did not is because he was sat on the other side of the car, in the passenger seat, where the force of the impact would've been a bit less severe. Had Vic's father, Silas, been there, and in the driver's seat himself, he would've been the one to take the worst of the impact, while Elinore likely would've been sat in the passenger seat, increasing her chances of survival.

There are other possible explanations. Just before the collision occurred, Elinore took her eyes off the road while trying to console Vic about his father's absence. Had Silas been there, that specific conversation never would've happened, and as such, the collision might've been avoided. Also, had Silas been there, they might've left the football stadium a little earlier, or a little later, which in itself could've prevented the collision.

Comment: I feel the kid is unjustly blaming his father.

Comment: Quite possibly. It's certainly unfair to the extent that there's no way his father could reasonably have predicted that his absence would lead to that outcome. That said, assuming that the collision wasn't something that was fated to happen -- that it was purely random, a case of bad timing -- then his father's presence would likely have altered the timing of their journey home enough that they wouldn't have been in the exact spot where the collision occurred at that exact moment.